# Volume expansion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> Consider a perfect monoatomic gas at pressure $p_i$ 1.2 atm and temperature $T_i$ 300K, that is in equilibrium inside a cylinder having a volume $V_i=1L$ and which piston has a mass of 1kg and is at an height of 50 cm. Admit that a mass M=3.13kg is over the piston. When that mass is removed, the gas suffers an adiabatic expansion until a final pressure pf=1.04837, a final temperature Tf and a final volume Vf.

What is the value of Vi/Vf?

So my immediate thought was to use the equation of real gases 
$$pV=nRT$$
´
We will have then 
$$\frac{p_iV_i}{T_i}=\frac{p_fV_f}{T_f}$$

But I also don't know Tf so I'm stuck. Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Use the first law of thermodynamics.

Comment: So I know that if the expansion is Adiabatic Q=0. So $ \delta U = W $ Now W = - pressure * volume variation. But I don't know the work...

Comment: Can someone help me?

Comment: What is the area of the piston, and how much do the two weights contribute to the total initial pressure?  What is the outside air pressure?

Comment: Ideal gases have an additional constraint if the expansion is adiabatic. Go find that constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answers to my questions are correct.  So we can continue.

The work $W^*$ done by the gas on its surroundings (the inside face of the piston) is equal to the increase in potential energy of the piston $mg\Delta z$ plus the work required to push the atmosphere back $p_{atm}\Delta V$:
$$W^*=mg\Delta z+p_{atm}\Delta V=\frac{mg}{A}\Delta V+p_{atm}\Delta V=\left(\frac{mg}{A}+p_{atm}\right)\Delta V\tag{1}$$The term in parenthesis in this equation is just equal to the final pressure of the gas (in its final equilibrium state):  $$\frac{mg}{A}+p_{atm}=p_f\tag{2}$$
(Please confirm to satisfy yourself that this is the case for the parameter values that they specified in this problem)

So the work done by the gas on its surroundings reduces to:
$$W^*=p_f\Delta V\tag{3}$$
And, from the first law of thermodynamics we have that:$$\Delta U=nC_v(T_f-T_i)=-p_f(V_f-V_i)=-p_f\left(\frac{nRT_f}{p_f}-\frac{nRT_i}{p_i}\right)\tag{4}$$
Note that the number of moles n cancel from both sides of this equation.  The only parameter that is unknown in this equation is the final temperature $T_f$.  I leave it up to you to solve for $T_f$.

Answer (score -1):

You can use $$P_{i}V_{i}^{\gamma}=P_{f}V_{f}^{\gamma}$$ where $\gamma$ is the ratio of molar specific heat, which is 5/3 for a monoatomic ideal gas.

Comment: Thank you for going straight to the point. I did not know that expression. Thanks again!

Comment: This is incorrect.  The expansion is irreversible, and at constant external pressure.

Comment: But I obtained the correct answer (given by my professor).  What is the correct way then? Answering your questions: the area of the piston is 2* 10^-3 (initial volume over height) and initially piA=patm A + (m+M)*g. Outside air pressure is 1 atm

Comment: Please help me...